# Does the inner product of wavefunctions really have units?

Tags: hilbert-space, wavefunction, probability, dimensional-analysis, normalization

Let $\psi(x)$ and $\phi(x)$ be wavefunctions. I usually see the inner product defined as
$$\int dx\, \overline{\psi(x)} \, \phi(x)$$
and interpreted, I think, as "the amplitude that state $\phi$ will fluctuate to state $\psi$".

Here dx could be a line element in a 1-dimensional problem, or replace it with $d^3 x$ a volume element in a 3d problem, or with $d^{3N} x$ a higher-dim volume element in a configuration space for an $N$-body problem.

I haven't thought of it before but it bothers me a lot that this expression for the inner product has units, and seemingly different units depending on the kind of problem: length, or volume, or $3N$-volume.

How do professionals address this?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot that the wave functions need to satisfy the [normalization condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function#Normalization_condition):
$$\int dx\, \overline{\psi(x)} \, \psi(x) = 1$$
$$\int dx\, \overline{\phi(x)} \, \phi(x) = 1$$

Hence the wavefunctions $\psi(x)$ and $\phi(x)$
have a unit of length$^{-1/2}$.
And therefore the inner product
$$\int dx\, \overline{\psi(x)} \, \phi(x)$$
comes out as unit-less.

Comment: Thomas, if dx is a length, phi(x) and psi(x) are inverse lengths, then the integrand and integral do not come out unitless, it seems to me. Maybe you prefer to give the units of length-to-the-power-of-minus-one-half? (Really?)

Comment: @Upasker oops yes, I forgot the one-half